# How to rotate Lottie animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, transformation, lottie

I have a Flutter app that is showing some Lottie animations. I sometimes need to flip the animation by 180 degrees on Y axis so that it it is a mirror image of itself.

In C# this is easily achievable by setting animated visual player's plane projection `rotationY` property to 180 (see below).

```
  <muxc:AnimatedVisualPlayer x:Name="LottiePlayer">
            <muxc:AnimatedVisualPlayer.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection RotationY="180" x:Name="LottiePayerRotation"/>
            </muxc:AnimatedVisualPlayer.Projection>
```

In flutter I tried using `RotationBox`, but that only rotates around X axis. I need to rotate around Y axis (see image below).

[image: rotation planes]

I also tried wrapping Lottie animation inside `Transform` widget (see below), but that doesn't work. After I added that, the Lottie animation completely disappears. I don't quite understand how `Matrix4` works, there is very little documentation on it. I found this [Matrix4 explanation](https://medium.com/flutter-community/advanced-flutter-matrix4-and-perspective-transformations-a79404a0d828) but I still don't understand it. :-(

```
Transform(
            transform: Matrix4(
              1,0,0,0,
              0,1,0,0,
              0,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,1,
          )..rotateX(0)..rotateY(180)..rotateZ(0),
            child: Lottie(
              frameRate: FrameRate.max,
              composition: _composition,
              controller: _controller,
            ),
          ),
```

Note that I do not need the flip to be animated, I just want to flip the Lottie animation instantly so that it looks like a mirror image of itself. So an instant change, not a transition animated.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I almost had it! What was missing was the `alignment`. The default value was causing the rotation to get outside the visible area. Changing alignment to "center" fixed that:

```
child: Transform(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
        transform: Matrix4(
          1,0,0,0,
          0,1,0,0,
          0,0,1,0,
          0,0,0,1,
        )..rotateY(180),
        child: Lottie(
          frameRate: FrameRate.max,
          composition: _composition,
          controller: _controller,
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this before to rotate items...  not sure if its what you are after

```
child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: 180 / Math.pi, // Rotations are supplied in radians
               child: Container())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. But that rotates on X axis, same as what RotationBox widget does. I need it to be inverted on Y axis. So a "\" should become "/". See the image in my question that shows different axes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap your widget with `RotatedBox` & give `quarterTurns` value(0, 1, 2, 3)

Assuming my widget is image of right arrow : `→`

`0` no rotation  - `→`

`1` 90 rotation  - `↓`

`2` 180 rotation - `←`

`3` 270 rotation - `↑`

So if I want my image to face left side `←`:

```dart
RotatedBox(
    quarterTurns: 2,
    child: Image.asset('assets/right_arrow.png'),
),
```

**EDIT**

To rotate on *axis*, you need to use `Transform` widget.
Give the `transform` property as `Matrix4`

NOTE: You have to give rotation in `radians`.

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math; 

Transform(
    // to mirror, rotate Y axis
    // math.pi is 180 degree in radian 
    transform: Matrix4.rotationY(math.pi), 
    child: Text('Hello world!'),
),
```

Comment: That does rotation on Z axis (see my picture). I need it to rotate on Y axis

Comment: yep, as per answer from April